# How to fetch params of a collection_select tag with ROR

Tags: arrays, ruby, select, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a rails application where i have a a multiple select box as such

```
 = section.collection_select(:room_ids, @rooms, :id, :location, {prompt:false}, {multiple: true, class: 'form-control list2' , required: true })
 = section.submit "", class: "save-btn"
```

In my sections controller i want to create an array of all the multiple items selected from the select box

I am trying something like

```
    class SectionsController < InheritedResources::Base
  respond_to :html,:js
  before_action :get_rooms, only: [:edit,:new]

  def create
      room_ids = params[:room_ids]
      if room_ids.count > 20
        flash[:error] = "Too many rooms selected"
        redirect_to sections_path
      else
        create! { sections_path }
      end
  end

  def update
    update! { sections_path }
  end

  protected

  def permitted_params
    params.permit(section: [:name, :section_time, :credits, room_ids: []])
  end

  def get_rooms
    @unassigned_rooms = Room.left_outer_joins(:section).where("rooms.section_id IS ?", nil).order('rooms.location asc').all.map{ |room| [ room.location, room.id, { credit: room.credit } ] }
    @rooms = @section.rooms
  end

end
```

But this doesn't work and gives me an error which says

```
undefined local variable or method `room_id' for #<SectionsController:0x007fc4ca7808c0> Did you mean? room_url
```

I tried changing the name of `collection_select` to `room_ids[]` but that didn't help either it gives me error  saying

```
wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2)
```

I am basically trying to do is user creates section of multiple rooms, by choosing rooms from the select box , but a user can only assign 20 rooms per section

Can anyone suggest me what i am doing wrong or some another alternative that i can try?

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an unexpected field name with `room_id[] = ...`

You should be doing...

```
room_ids = params[:room_ids]
if room_ids.count > 20
```

Comment: i had tried that too but that gives me this error `undefined method `count' for nil:NilClass` @SteveTurczyn

Comment: Ok, add `gem 'pry'` to your development group in your Gemfile, then set the first line of your `create` method to be `binding.pry` and run in development.  When the server halts, type in `params` to see what your params look like and to see if you have a `params[:room_ids]`